# Symfony5 non-service classes - how to get services (like EntityManager)

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, dependency-injection, symfony5

The problem:

> producer A produces 50 products

> producer A sells its products through 300+ resellers across the world

> each reseller demands the product sheets in a different structure/format/attributes etc.

Because:

> I need 300+ methods to build each reseller's format, looped 50 times (for each product)

I guess that:

> placing all 300+ methods in one class (in one 5000+ lines service class) is ugly, anti-design etc.

> creating 300+ services (SellerX, each containing a method to create the product sheet) and auto-wiring them in the caller service __construct() is also no-go (the caller service being the one to loop the 300 methods 50 times)

Remaining option: strategy design pattern, with an interface class to be implemented 300+ times for each of the 300+ SellerX (to implement the method createProductSheet() in 300+ non-service classes). But how should the 300+ classes be built and used, in order to benefit from Symfony's EntityManager service and other useful Services that I need?

The big problem with this approach is that, in the calling code, I would somehow need to (first) instantiate a SellerX object with the NEW keyword (dynamic instantiation) AND pass each required service as argument (which would again turn ugly when tens of extra services are required in any of the createProductSheet() methods; furthermore, not all SellerX methods need all the services that would be passed as a bulk).

Whether the 300+ implementations of the method createProductSheet() are Singletons, static methods classes, or regular classes (non-singletons, non-static methods), the main problem is the same: I cannot use dependency injection.

Is there a way to access services like EntityManager from custom classes? From the Kernel? How?

Or, perhaps, is there any other possibility?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking for.  I will say that trying to create and manage 15,000 services will be challenging regardless of the approach taken.  I would really question the need to do this before proceeding but you of course know your requirements the best.  You might want to take a look at [service locators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html). The basic idea is that a service locator might make it easier to access your product sheet services.

Comment: If you really feel that DI is not practical (and I don't think you have really shown it) then it is possible to access services globally.  Might want to take a look at Laravel's Facades as an example.  $kernel is globally accessible and from that you can get the container and hence a service.  Wrap it all up in a static method and you can basically access your services globally.  Might be a starting point just to get things going.